# php proc_open returning NULL

Tags: php, proc-open

I keep getting a return value of NULL from proc_open with php 7.2, what could be the cause on windows, the spawned process pid is valid though :

```
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin for worker
        1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout for worker
        2 => array("pipe", "w"), // stderr for worker
    );
    $user->worker = proc_open('C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.18\php watch.php', $descriptorspec, $user->pipes); 
    if(is_resource($user->worker)) 
    {
        $ppid = proc_get_status($user->worker)['pid'];
        echo "WORKER:".var_export($user->worker, true)." pid ".$ppid);
    }
```

this is stored in a public member "worker" of an instance of a derived class "user"

should I try array('bypass_shell'=>true) );
perhaps as option to proc_open, thank you for any clues

from var_dump : "resource(16) of type (process)"
from var_export : 'worker' => NULL,

Comment: Resources can't be exported, serialized, or otherwise be transmitted outside of the context of the current execution. If you just want to _look_ at the fact that it is a resource in a debugging context you should be using `var_dump()` as it produces proper representations most reliably aside from actual debuggers.

Comment: Did you verified if "proc_open" is enabled or not. Generally its working on local pc in local host but not enabled in cPanel for security reason. I suggest try do modify this line [ 2 => array('file', 'error-output.txt', 'a' ] and store any possible error in text file.